# PHP: Keeps return as true

Tags: php, foreach

I cant figure out what i´m doing wrong. I keeps returning "På lager" in the if statement. But Shop 3, should return "Ikke på lager" in the foreach loop, where it calls the function.

```
<?php

$shopsArray = array(
    "Shop1" => array (
        "price" => 5,
        "extUrl" => "https://tv2.dk/",
        "logo" => "",
        "stock" => "in stock",
        "ean" => "5707400342642",
        "shopName" => "Shop2",
    ),
    "Shop2" => array (
        "price" => 99,
        "extUrl" => "https://cnn.com/",
        "logo" => "https://eb.dk/",
        "stock" => "in stock",
        "ean" => "51010101010",
        "shopName" => "Shop2.dk",
    ),
    "Shop3" => array (
        "price" => 50000000,
        "extUrl" => "https://v2.dk/",
        "logo" => "https://eb.dk/",
        "stock" => "out of stock",
        "ean" => "5707406556565655",
        "shopName" => "Shop3",
    )

    );

foreach($shopsArray as $abc){
    echo CheckStock();
}
function checkStock(){
    global $shopsArray;

    foreach ($shopsArray as $stockMgmt) {

        if ($stockMgmt["stock"] == "in stock"){
            return "På lager";
        } else {
            return "Ikke på lager";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you calling a function that loops inside that loop? and why do you use globlal instead of arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `return` from your `checkStock()` function as soon as `$stockMgmt["stock"] == "in stock"`, and you do that three times. Try this code instead:

```
<?php

$shops = [
    "Shop1" => [
        "price" => 5,
        "stock" => "in stock",
        "ean" => "5707400342642",
        "shopName" => "Shop2",
    ],
    "Shop2" => [
        "price" => 99,
        "stock" => "in stock",
        "ean" => "51010101010",
        "shopName" => "Shop2.dk",
    ],
    "Shop3" => [
        "price" => 50000000,
        "stock" => "out of stock",
        "ean" => "5707406556565655",
        "shopName" => "Shop3",
    ]
];

function checkStock($stockManagement)
{
    return ($stockManagement["stock"] == "in stock") ? "På lager" : "Ikke på lager";
}

foreach ($shops as $shop => $stockManagement) {
   echo $shop . ' = ' . CheckStock($stockManagement) . '<br>';
}
```

The function now uses the stock management array as an argument. In the function I use the [Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

We only use one loop to walk through the main array of shops.

Note how I don't abbreviate unnecessarily. Variable names should clarify the meaning of the value, but not the type. So, not `$shopsArray` but just `$shops` or `$shopsStock`.

Now tested, thanks to medilies: [PHP fiddle](https://3v4l.org/cp1Z5)

Comment: some syntactic fixes https://3v4l.org/PRmPT

Comment: @medilies It should be `($shopKey + 1)` not `($shopKey . 1)`. But yes, I did make some mistakes.

Comment: I´m not really sure how to use this. Sorry. I´m really new to programming, so this is also a learning path for me (Thanks for the comment about abrevation).

I have tried implmenting it this way:

Comment: foreach ($shopsArray as $shopKey => $stockManagement) {
        echo "Shop " . ($shopKey + 1) . ' = ' . CheckStock($stockManagement) . '<br>';
     }

function checkStock($stockMgmt)
{
    return ($stockManagement["stock"] == "in stock") ? "På lager" : "Ikke på lager";
}

But it returns:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + int in C:\xampp\htdocs\maritimoButtonGenerator\testing.php:32 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\maritimoButtonGenerator\testing.php on line XX.

Comment: @MickeyRasmussen visit the link that I commented up, this is valid solution

Comment: @MickeyRasmussen I corrected some errors and added a "fiddle" (running example). The one from medilies also works.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware `$shopKey` is a string. using the `+` operator throws `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + int ...` or `Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in ...`

Comment: @medilies Yes, you're right. I assumed a numeric key. See my changed answer.

Comment: It works now, after @medilies corrected something. Now i need to figure out WHY it works. 

But thanks to everyone for the solution.

Comment: @MickeyRasmussen: The first sentence in my answer addresses why your code didn't work.